# Editing css by js in ie giving error

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, edit

I need to do this:

```
document.styleSheets[i].rules[1].style.cssText = "cursor: url(images/grabbing.cur), default !important;";
```

and if I'm checking:

```
alert(document.styleSheets[i].rules[1].style.cssText);
```

its giving: `cursor: !important`

Why is it not setting the whole string in this css?

It's a problem in Internet Explorer only, it works in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

A simple tipo: there is no ", default" needed.

in css the character "," just uses to seperate items in a list like:

```
font-family: tahoma, times;
```

and the `cursor` property does not accept a serie as value.

the correct form for your css:

```
cursor: url(images/grabbing.cur) !important;
```

feather reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Hey it doesnt work also
i tried this
document.styleSheets[i].rules[1].style.cssText = "cursor: url(images/grabbing.cur) !important;";
alert(document.styleSheets[i].rules[1].style.cssText);
its giving the same
"cursor: !important" value by alert.